# undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

In my model email token i have

```
def self.token_valid(token, type)
   return unless token.present?
   token = EmailToken.where("token = ? and verification_type = ? and confirmed = 'false' and created_at <= ?", token, type, EmailToken.expires).includes(:user).first
   user = token.user
 end
```

And I call this method from my controller

```
def confirm_password_reset
    @user = EmailToken.token_valid(params[:pass_reset],"password")
    render 'reset_password' if @user
end
```

The conditions are valid because I've tested it without trying to associate it with the user and it works. What I'm trying to do is to get `token_valid` method to confirm the token and return both the token and it's associated user.
The `belongs_to` and `has_many` del have also been defined.
`Current error : undefined method user for nil:NilClass`
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to make your model return token, then in your reset_password view inspect the @user obj

```
<%= @user.inspect %>
```

My guess is that it returns and empty array. If you're using sqlite you might want to read this
[ref doc](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) about boolean data types in sqlite. So you might want to change your confirmed field to 0 for false and 1 for true.

```
token = EmailToken.where("token = ? and verification_type = ? and confirmed = 0 and created_at <= ?", token, type, EmailToken.expires).includes(:user).first
```

If not, check spelling mistakes in your tables.

Comment: Thnks didn't know that, that was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This line :

```
 token = EmailToken.where("token = ? and verification_type = ? and confirmed = 'false' and created_at <= ?", token, type, EmailToken.expires).includes(:user).first
```

returns nil.