# Rails undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello everyone I am new to rails and for some reason I keep getting an error

`undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass`.

I have pasted an image of the error on the bottom and I posted the code below.

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkf3k.png)

`# registeredapps_controller.rb`

```
class RegisteredappsController < ApplicationController

 def create
   @registeredapp = Registeredapp.new(registeredapp_params)
   @registeredapp.user = current_user

  unless RegisteredappPolicy.new(current_user, @registeredapp).create?
    flash[:alert] = "not authorized" 
    redirect_to user_registeredapps_path(current_user.id)
  end

  if @registeredapp.save
    flash[:notice] = "You successfully registered your app."
    redirect_to user_registeredapp_path(current_user.id, @registeredapp.id)
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error registering your app. Please try again."
    render :new
  end
end
```

Policies (using Pundit Gem)
`# registeredapp_policy.rb`

```
class RegisteredappPolicy 

  def initialize(user, registeredapp)
    @registeredapp = registeredapp
    @user = user
  end

  def create?
    if @user.present?
     @user = @registerdapp.user
    else
     false
  end
end
```

Here are my models

`# models/user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  def avatar_url(size)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(self.email).downcase
    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=#{size}"
  end

  has_many :registeredapps
end
```

`# models/registeredapp.rb`

```
class Registeredapp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :events
end
```

Comment: Can you provide your rails version?

Comment: It's a spelling issue...check your instance variable (see my answer for more details)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method \`user' for nil:NilClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383294/undefined-method-user-for-nilnilclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the instance variable `@registeredapp` is mispelled in the `RegisteredappPolicy` class under the `create?` method.

It currently is

```
def create?
  if @user.present?
    @user = @registerdapp.user
  else
    false
  end
end
```

whereas the variable defined in the initialize is `@registeredapp` you're missing an `e`

Answer (score 0):

`@registerdapp` is `nil`

```
@user = @registerdapp.user
```

use `try`

```
@user = @registerdapp.try(:user)
```

or

```
def create?
  if @user.present? && @registerdapp.present?
    @user = @registerdapp.user
  else
    false
  end
end
```

**NOTE:** Also you are missing one `end` for `if else` in `create?` method

Answer (score 0):

Rails convention usually is to have the model name like:

```
User
```

And its corresponding table name like:

```
users
```

In your ActiveRecord::Registeredapp you have `:user`, check if you shouldn't have `:users`.